# WritePrinter not asking for PIN Code

Tags: c++, winapi

We have something like Secure Print.

I go to my control panel >> Printers and Devices >> Printer >> Printer Preference
Here i assign a 4 digit pin code ..

I fire a print from Word or Excel ... go to the printer >> retrieve jobs >> select my print job and enter my pin code.

Only then my job gets printed.

Now Our application has two source codes for printing

While firing print from our Application the print is instantaneously done .... I.e. it doesn't store my job in the queue and wait for pin ... but just prints immediately

Some source code

```
bResult = OpenPrinter(szDevice, &hPrinter, NULL);
// szDevice contains printer name
startDocPrtInfo.pDocName = msg;
startDocPrtInfo.pOutputFile = NULL;
startDocPrtInfo.pDatatype = "RAW";
bPrntErr = (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter,1,(LPBYTE)&startDocPrtInfo) == 0);

WritePrinter(hPrinter, &buffer[2], i, &cnt);
EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
```

~~~~~
The Code is printing the given document however its not waiting for user to enter his pin code

QUESTION
How to make the above code wait just like its doing for other applications ? is there some setting that I am missing here ?

Thanks in Anticipation 
CP

Comment: possible duplicate of [Win32 API Print not asking user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760839/win32-api-print-not-asking-user-input)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this.

There are NO CODE CHANGES. 
In our Printer Settings, we UNCHECKED the "Allow Escape Sequence" and it worked.

Thanks to the forum tho for entertaining the question.
Will visit often with more questions and resolutions to Questions that others raise

Good Luck 
A Clueless Programmer :)