# Win32 API Print not asking user input

Tags: c++, c, winapi

We have something like [Secure Print](http://secureprint.com.au/).

I go to my control panel >> Printers and Devices >> Printer >> Printer Preference Here i assign a 4 digit pin code ..

I fire a print from Word or Excel ... go to the printer >> retrieve jobs >> select my print job and enter my pin code.

Only then my job gets printed.

Now Our application has two source codes for printing

While firing print from our Application the print is instantaneously done .... I.e. it doesn't store my job in the queue and wait for pin ... but just prints immediately

Some source code

```
bResult = OpenPrinter(szDevice, &hPrinter, NULL);
// szDevice contains printer name
startDocPrtInfo.pDocName = msg;
startDocPrtInfo.pOutputFile = NULL;
startDocPrtInfo.pDatatype = "RAW";
bPrntErr = (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter,1,(LPBYTE)&startDocPrtInfo) == 0);

WritePrinter(hPrinter, &buffer[2], i, &cnt);
EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
```

The Code is printing the given document however its not waiting for user to enter his pin code

QUESTION How to make the above code wait just like its doing for other applications ? is there some setting that I am missing here ?

To give you more details .

We have another Print subroutine in the same application that works as desierd .. I.e. waits for User to enter his PIN

However the subroutine uses TextOut method instead of WritePrinter

Any idea why print is not waiting when i use the WritePrinter methods of printing?

Thanks in Anticipation CP

Comment: You are bypassing the normal printing plumbing when you directly print to the printer like that.  Which is indeed a good way to get to print stuff without some kind of custom print monitor being aware of it so it can charge printed pages to a particular user.  You'll need to talk to the LAN admin to find out what kind of software is in place that does this so you can contact the vendor for support.

Comment: The feature is from the printer. I assign a 4 digit PIN from the printer Preference dialog box. Some printers call it Stored Print etc ... So I believe its a printing functionality rather than some external software...Moreover our TextOut code works fine

Comment: "From the printer" == "external software".  Microsoft doesn't write printer drivers.  When you use TextOut then you are not using WritePrinter, that goes through the printer driver as normal.  Which is certainly the best way to avoid this trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this.

There is NO CODE CHANGES.
In our Printer Settings, we need to UNCHECK the "Allow Escape Sequence"

Thanks to the forum tho for entertaining the question.

Will visit often with more questions and resolutions to Questions that others raise

Good Luck
A Clueless Programmer :)